# get value after specific word

Tags: shell, string

I have this file

```
1 deiauk David Smith from California 12 58
2 edvin from Nevada 12 5 8 95 2 48 5
3 jaco My Name Is Jacob I'm from NY 5  6  845 156 585
4 from Miami
```

And I need to get values after specific word `from` is it possible to do that in shell?
My output should be

```
California
Nevada
NY
Miami
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or:

```
awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "from") print $(I+1)}' file
```

Comment: Kindly, how can this command output five words or numbers after "from"?

Answer (score 21):

Using `grep`, it can be done as follows:

```
grep -oP "from\s+\K\w+" input.txt
```

Here,

```
-o  ==>  option for printing only the matching part of the line
-P  ==>  use perl-regexp
\K  ==>  do not print that comes before \K (zero-width look-behind assertion)
\w  ==>  match word characters
```

Comment: Wow, that look behind assertion looks way easier than vim's.  Does Perl subscribe to a standard RegEx (if there is such a thing) or is it just a lot easier to understand?

Comment: @user1717828 I don't know what RegEx Perl subscribes to, but the cheat-sheet I have with me is based on Perl regex. Moreover, perl regex is more powerful than the basic and extended RegEx.

Comment: @user1717828, that's not a look-behind assertion, it sets the start of the matched portion, so it can replace a look-behind assertion (here the Perl/PCRE look behind assertion would be `(?<=from\s+)`, except that in `perl` (contrary to `vim`'s `\v(from\s+)\@<=`) look-behinds can only be of fixed length so wouldn't work)

Answer (score 8):

A readable solution would be:

```
awk -F '${fixed_string}' '{print $2}' file | awk '{print $1}'
```

What it does:

- `-F '${fixed_string}'` separates the input into before and after the given string. So with your file, when we set `fixed_string='from'`, `print $2` would give:

  `California 12 58
   Nevada 12 5 8 95 2 48 5 
   NY 5  6  845 156 585 
   Miami`
- Now, all you need is the 1st column of this input. So we pipe the output of the first `awk` to `awk` and print the 1st column.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more about what's going on here? Why would `${fixed_string}` be a good field separator, for example, and why do you pipe the output of `awk` through `awk` again?

Comment: @Kusalananda Honestly, I couldn't figure out a readable solution to do it using just one awk.

Comment: Point for idea of using the match word as the separator. Easy to remember. @Jignesh Darji I'm not sure what the `${}` is for around `fixed_string`?. Mine worked by simply using `awk -F 'from' ...` format.

Comment: `awk` is awesome, thanks for this simple and easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` one liner does it:

```
 sed '/from/s/.*from \([^ ][^ ]*\)[ ]*.*/\1/' input
```

I'm presuming a space character before the "from" literal string. If you want to have tab-separated fields, you might have to insert a tab-character in all three character-range-match expressions, those between '[' and ']'.

Comment: It will get the last - but it might strip other *from*s in doing so.

Comment: Just an improvement after removing some redundancies `sed 's/.*from \([^ ]*\)[ ]*.*/\1/' input`

Answer (score 1):

Assume the file name is test.txt

```
$ cat test.txt
deiauk David Smith from California 12 58
edvin from Nevada 12 5 8 95 2 48 5
jaco My Name Is Jacob I'm from NY 5  6  845 156 585
from Miami
```

You can use `sed` to grep everything after `from` then `cut` the output like this.

```
$ cat test.txt | sed 's/.*from //' | cut -d " " -f 1
California
Nevada
NY
Miami
```